# How do I check my remaining IBM Q credits?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I've already tried the approach in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6346), but I'm getting this error:

```
IBMQuantumExperience.IBMQuantumExperience.CredentialsError: error during login: License required. You need to accept the License from Web Platform. https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net
```

However, I've already accepted the terms, and have already successfully run two experiments using the Qiskit SDK, like the ones in the [docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/executing_quantum_programs.html#executing-quantum-programs).

I'm suspecting `IBMQuantumExperience`, and by extension [qiskit-api-py](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-api-py) might be out of date, superceded by [qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit). My question is then this: is it possible to check my remaining credits using the new library, and if so, how? If not, how else can I check my credits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `IBMQuantumExperience` is a deprecated library. Anything you wanted to use `IBMQuantumExperience` to do you can now do through [`qiskit-ibmq-provider`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider).

To answer your main question, the credit system is being removed in the future, so there is currently no way to check your remaining credits. The feature used to be in the old IBM Q Experience page, but since the new, beta version has been launched it no longer has that capability.

Comment: What will replace the credit system?

Comment: any reply to @Andrea 's question after more than half a year?

Comment: @silgon At the moment, the credit system is still in place, but it was reworked. Users now can have up to 5 jobs submitted at any on time. Once they hit that 5 job limit, they must wait until at least one of those jobs finish before being able to send another.

Comment: Independent of number of shots, or circuits per job?

Comment: @Andrea As far as I know, independent of those factors, yes.