# What is the IBM Q credits?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I find in [this link](https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmqx-user-guides/blob/master/rst/full-user-guide/000-FAQ/000-Frequently_Asked_Questions.rst) that

> "A User has a maximum of 15 credits, and these credits are replenished upon the greater of 24 hours or when your execution has run off the queue."

But what is credit? Is it necessary to deduct one credit when using IBMQ for one operation? Can I use for loop to run 100 times?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits are a way of monitoring the queue, so that no one can add too many jobs to the queue at once, preventing other people from using the device. Depending on the length of your circuit, a variable number of credits will be used. For example, if you only have 10 gates in your circuit it may take 3 credits, but a circuit with 100 gates may take 4 or 5 credits.

As stated in the answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/how-do-i-check-my-remaining-ibm-q-credits) the credits system is being deprecated, so it won't be a concern for much longer.